# Does ZFS replace the need for hardware/software RAID?

Tags: filesystems, solaris, freebsd, raid, zfs

I want to provide protection against data loss on my servers.

Typically, I'd use hardware RAID 1 or 5, but I've been reading up on [**ZFS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS).

Is it correct that ZFS itself provides RAID 1 or 5 like data protection WITHOUT needing a RAID controller card?

If so, I assume a single hard drive is not enough to provide data protection since if that drive fails, all data fails, so how many hard drives do I need to be running for ZFS to provide this protection?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, ZFS doesn't need hardware raid and is actually better when used without it.

It is able to provide partial data protection even with a single device when configured to use ditto blocks but of course won't resist a full disk failure in that case.

You can use it in a mirror configuration (two devices or more) or a RAIDZ one (three devices or more) to survive failures. RAID-Z2 and RAID-Z3 provide 2 and 3 concurrent device failures protection.

Comment: +1 It's highly recommend to *not* use a Hardware RAID controller with ZFS.

Comment: How well does that scale? Saying to a little small 4U case with 72 disc slots?

Comment: @TomTom That depends on how you organize your pool(s) which itself depends on your goals.

Comment: @TomTom - also depends on how much RAM is in the system.  ZFS is pretty memory hungry.  Also be wary of heat if you have 72 disks in a 4U chassis.

Comment: Hardly. Check SuperMicro - they offer those cases and they are perfectly fine heat wise ;) THis is not a hommade solution, it is pretty much an enterprise component. I currently use 22 discs for storage and they approach a too alrge fill factor.

Comment: The SuperMicro gear is pretty great for that sort of thing. The only thing I've been burnt on is that even some of their "new" products are still SAS 1.0; slow and lacking table-table routing. Not a big deal for low performance archival stuff. Most of their gear is top notch however, just have to double check what you're buying. The same really goes for any vendor I suppose.