# 6* HDD ,2*SSD, Freebsd, Raidz2 or hardware R6?

Tags: freebsd, raidz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does ZFS replace the need for hardware/software RAID?](https://serverfault.com/questions/396331/does-zfs-replace-the-need-for-hardware-software-raid)

I want to install Freebsd 9 on our servers.
We have 6 HDD and 2SDD. SDD will be used for database.
For now we're planning to use Raidz2 for HDD instead of Hardware Raid.
But for 2 SSD, I'm not use which choice is better, ZFS raidz1 or Hardware Raid1?

And can anyone please help to provide a document about how to install Freebsd 9 on bootable Raidz2?

I have found a document, but it's used for Freebsd 8.Some commands don' work on Freebsd9

http://freebsdwiki.net/index.php/ZFS,_booting_from
http://wiki.freebsd.org/RootOnZFS/GPTZFSBoot/RAIDZ2

Comment: This question really has two parts. The first is an exact duplicate of the "Duplicate Question". The second part, you can't boot from a RAIDZ, you can only boot from a mirror. You'll want to carve off about 1GB for a root partition on each disk for a mirror (I'd recommend using the SSDs for this, and the rest of the SSDs in 2 more mirrored partitions for L2Arc and ZIL), which will include /boot, and put the rest of the disks in a RAIDZ. If you want more details on how to do this please ask. I personally run a setup *very* similar to this. We've got a couple FreeBSD and ZFS experts around too.

Comment: Also, we've got online chat where people can ask for general recommendations and such (discussion questions are off-topic on the actual site, hence chat). Be warned that we're not always around on chat, so it may take some time going back and forth. Looks like you might not have enough rep to participate in general chat... if that's the case let me know and I'll "invite" you so you can.

Answer (score -3):

I do not have much experience with ZFS raidz1, but I prefer gmirror to hardware RAID1 for ease of management.

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/geom-mirror.html